# Use custom HTML with YouTube video in Fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

I'm trying to open a YouTube video with Fancybox but also have some additional HTML in the Fancybox window. So the end goal is to have the video pulling from YouTube and then underneath it some text and a learn more button pulling from my site. I don't want to embed the videos.

I thought about passing the video url as a variable like so, but I feel like there should be an easier way. I'm having trouble parsing the url out on the fancybox page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.youtube").click(function() {
       var vidLink = $(this).attr("rel");
         $.fancybox({
           'href'   : 'player.html?page=' + vidLink,
            'type'  : 'iframe'
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a class="youtube" href="#" rel="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvAK5crfRLc">The Video</a>
```

Then on player.html

```
<script>
    function show_video() {
      var newVid = urlParams["vidLink"];
      document.getElementById("vidPlayer").setAttribute('src', newVid);
    }
</script>

<iframe id="vidPlayer" src="" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<h3><a href="#">Learn More</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

player.html will never be able to grab a variable out of the query string. You'll have to use something like PHP to get the variable.

You could also use javascript and read through the location.search object for all the query string params.

[See Here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/location_search.html)